# Number of users can be created in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a web project with Django, and using postgresql for storing informations. I'd like to know what is the maximum number of users can we create in postgresql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between Django application users and Postgresql database users. If you intend to create users in your django application, and you are using Postgresql as your django backend database, then for each user you will create will be represented as a row in a postgresql table - therefore, **practically speaking, you can create as many users as you'd like and there's no limit**. I believe the most commonly used authentication models are defined in `django.contrib.auth` - there you can find django models for users and groups. In postgresql itself you'd normally have very few database users defined - in all likelihood just one - the user you connect with from Django.

Comment: Oh Okey i understand, thank you @Legato. I saw in the database of the project some tables like auth_users, in wich the user that i will create to loggin to the project web will be stored. In this case, it's not necessary to create user in postgresql. that's correct what i said ?

Comment: When configuring your django application you'll need to first create a postgresql database and a database user (e.g, use sql CREATE USER) and then from the django settings (settings.py) you'd point your application to this database and user (refer to the django docs for instructions). The `auth_user` table will store your application users later on - it will be one row per user, so it could potentially store an unlimited number of users (in django it will be a User.save() operation that adds rows to this table). Hope that clarifies. Once you have your project up and configured, you'll get it

Comment: Okey good, i underatand. Thank you so much Legato. It's very clear your explanation.